# Similar Div resized based on parent bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am trying to work out whether its possible to create one component that can be adapted based on parent requirements, either through bootstrap or through normal flex / css grid. Wanted to understand what the reusuability factor would be?

I have one component with an image and some text and i am trying to reuse it based on the bootstrap utilities

**Example Code**:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="row no-gutters text-white dy-fixed-height-content mt-4">
  <div class="col-lg-6">
    <div class="bg-dark p2 flex-fill">
      <div class="card__image"><img src="https://placeimg.com/640/480/any"></div>
      <div class="card__title">
        <a target="_blank" href="" class="card__title--link">Big item here</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-6">
    <div class="d-inline-flex flex-wrap flex-fill align-content-stretch">
      <div class="bg-dark p2 flex-fill">
        <div class="card__image"><img src="https://placeimg.com/640/480/any"></div>
        <div class="card__title">
          <a target="_blank" href="" class="card__title--link">Small item here</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="bg-dark p2 flex-fill">
        <div class="card__image"><img src="https://placeimg.com/640/480/any"></div>
        <div class="card__title">
          <a target="_blank" href="" class="card__title--link">Item here 2</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="bg-dark p2 flex-fill">
        <div class="card__image"><img src="https://placeimg.com/640/480/any"></div>
        <div class="card__title">
          <a target="_blank" href="" class="card__title--link">Item here 3</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="bg-dark p2 flex-fill">
        <div class="card__image"><img src="https://placeimg.com/640/480/any"></div>
        <div class="card__title">
          <a target="_blank" href="" class="card__title--link">example here</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**What am i trying to achieve**:

[image: What i am trying to achieve]

Comment: Do you have any strcture restrictions ? Some quick example with plain css :
https://jsfiddle.net/L9wa6po7/

Comment: There is one tile and i want that one tile to be fitted into different structures. Based on the example, there is a card with an image and with text over the top. @DaniP i think your example has replaced it with completely different structure

Comment: Content doesn't matter it is easy to replace them inside each car but is basically the same structure you have 1 big container > 2 columns container > # of cards inside those columns

Comment: Here you have a more complex example : 
https://jsfiddle.net/L9wa6po7/3/

Answer (score 0):

This should be pretty simple with plain css using `flex`, taking your same structure with one less container for the small ones and custom class names:

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
  align-items: stretch;
  justify-content: center
}

.column {
  flex: 0 0 50%;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.card {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  border: 1px dotted black;
}

.card a {
  padding: 10px;
  display: block;
}

.card img {
  max-width: 100%;
}

.column.multiple .card {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  flex-basis: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="column">
    <div class="card">
      <img src="https://placeimg.com/640/480/any">
      <a target="_blank" href="">Big item here</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column multiple">
    <div class="card">
      <img src="https://placeimg.com/640/480/any">
      <a target="_blank" href="">Small item here</a>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <img src="https://placeimg.com/640/480/any">
      <a target="_blank" href="">Small item here</a>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <img src="https://placeimg.com/640/480/any">
      <a target="_blank" href="">Small item here</a>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <img src="https://placeimg.com/640/480/any">
      <a target="_blank" href="">Small item here</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```